# Connecting to local instance of PostgreSql with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, connection-string, database-connection

I have a running local instance of PostgreSql on a linux machine. When I use `psql` command from the shell I success to log in without any problem. I need to connect to the PostgreSql via the JDBC, but I don't know what exactly should I pass as `url` parameter to `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

It should start with `jdbc:postgresql:` but what's going next?

I was told by the system group that a database with was created like user name. e.g. if my user is `jutky` a db named `jutky` was created, but when I try to open a connection to `jdbc:postgresql:jutky` I get an error

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "jutky"`
:(

*Additional info*

When I login via the `psql` I'm not prompted for the password, so when I try to login via JDBC I pass an empty string as a password - is it correct, or should I pass `null` or something?

When I type `psql --help` in the shell I see among the rest this line:

```
Connection options:
   -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory (default: "/var/run/postgresql")
```

So I understand that I connect to PostgreSql via a `socket directory`, does that matters something to the URL string in the JDBC?

---

**EDIT**

First thanks for the answers.

Second: its not first time I'm using JDBC and in particular not the first time I'm connecting to the PostgreSql from JDBC, so I know the general rules and I have read the documentations. However in the described case I'm not sure how exactly should I construct the connection string if the instance is running via the `socket directory` and what password should I provide. Because when I login via the `psql` I'm not prompted for password at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In addition to other answers note that by default Postgres is configured to accept connections via Unix sockets with authentication based on your operating system account, that's why `psql` works fine and doesn't require the password.

JDBC connections are made over TCP/IP with password authentication, so you need to modify `pg_hba.conf` accordingly. For example, this line allows TCP/IP connections from the same machine to all databases for all users with password authentication:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

After adding this line `jdbc:postgresql:databasename` should work.

**EDIT:** You can't create a JDBC connection over Unix socket since PostgreSQL JDBC driver can only work over TCP/IP. The password you use when creating JDBC connection is the password assigned to your user. If you don't have it, you can assign it, for example, using `ALTER USER` command. See [19.3. Authentication methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD).

**See also:**

- [19.1. The pg_hba.conf file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: I've asked the system group to check that issue. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Also make sure that listen_address = '*' is enabled in postgresql.conf. Otherwise TCP/IP connection will not be possible at all (which is what JDBC is using, even with a local connection)

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed the issue was solved by configuring the PostgreSql.

Comment: @axtavt please help me to edit the configuration file of postgresql i am not able to resolve the Connection Refused Error.

Comment: If I am using a virtual private server, do I still use the 127.0.0.1/32 IP address or the IP address of my the actual server?

Answer (score 7):

It's all explained in [official documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html).

This is the relevant part:

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```