# Connection problem of PostgreSQL and Netbeans Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, netbeans

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL from NetBeans, but it is showing some errors:

> Cannot establish a connection to `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres` using `org.postgresql.Driver` (The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the `pg_hba.conf` file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.)

I tried changing password in config file and also tried change the md5. How to resolve it and connect PostgreSQL using Java?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the JDBC driver.

Comment: @Andreas How to check that?

Comment: You are using an outdated JDBC driver. [Download](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) and install the current one that supports scram authentication. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64211633/)

Comment: Normally, the JDBC driver jar file name has the version number. Current latest version is **42.2.18**, so the file name is `postgresql-42.2.18.jar` for Java 8+ version.