# Databricks error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, connection, databricks

Currently, I have run code using spark with option jdbc on Databricks to connect to postgresql to get data. **PostgreSQL version 42.1.4, Databricks runtime 8.3**

Here is my code, and I would like to hide the database information:

```
df = (spark\
  .read\
  .format("jdbc")\
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://postgres.*******:5432/dbname?user=*******&password=******")\
  .option("dbtable", "schema.table_name")\
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")\
  .load()
)
df.printSchema()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client&#39;s IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
```

However, I can't find a way to fix this on Databricks

I hope you will help me fix this error on Databricks

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9GQu.png)

Comment: Weclome to StackOverflow! Did you look on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210167/unable-to-connect-to-postgres-db-due-to-the-authentication-type-10-is-not-suppor ?

Comment: However, I'm using Databricks so I can't do the above

Comment: The problem is not with Databricks itself but with correct combination of PostrgeSQL and drivers versions +  PostgreSQL configuration

Comment: This question would be more useful if you included the Postgres version and the JDBC driver version. If you do so add as update to your question. At a guess you have an older version of the JDBC driver that does recognize the new SCRAM authentication method.  The solution would be to upgrade the driver following the guidelines here [Download](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).

Comment: However, how to upgrade PostgreSQL version and access PostgreSQL configuration on Databricks? 
Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You need to upgrade to PostgreSQL JDBC 42.2.x for this, as suggested by the (currently) third [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65758688/466862) on that question.