How to import a SQL file on PostgreSQL 16?
I have a problem when I try to import a file to PostgreSQL.
I'm using Postgresql 16.3 on Windows but whenever I try to import a new file (.sql) it doesn't work! My process on Postbird: File -> Import .sql file -> I select my sql file -> Import database -> Error! And it shows me an error that says:

" Import Options Importing File:
C:\Users\aorla\Downloads\TheBestOfBaseballAwards\baseball_dataset.sql
Select database 'baseball' psql: authentication method 10 not supported FAILURE "

The error on Postbird
I even tried some other methods, like going to SQL shell directly and try it from there using: "\i C:\Users\aorla\Downloads\TheBestOfBaseballAwards\baseball_dataset.sql" but it threw me an error again, saying:

"C:: Permission denied".

I was expecting that this would solve the problem but it didn't.
Then, I also tried from cmd using this command:
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=baseball --username=postgres --files=C:\\Users\\aorla\\Downloads\\TheBestOfBaseballAwards\\baseball_dataset.sql

And it's error:

psql: illegal option -- files=C:\Users\aorla\Downloads\TheBestOfBaseballAwards\baseball_dataset.sql psql: hint: Try "psql --help" for more information."


Perhaps this link will help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210167/unable-to-connect-to-postgres-db-due-to-the-authentication-type-10-is-not-suppor].

You have a typo in psql command
--files ❌  it will be --file ✅
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=baseball --username=postgres --file=C:\\Users\\aorla\\Downloads\\TheBestOfBaseballAwards\\baseball_dataset.sql


The psql command-line argument you're after is called --file=, not --files=.
Additionally, you don't need to escape backslashes on Windows, and you probably should use double-quotes with --file= just-to-be-safe.
So change your command-line to this:
(Literal line-breaks with ^ added for readability btw)
psql ^
    --host=localhost ^
    --port=5432 ^
    --dbname=baseball ^
    --username=postgres ^
    --file="C:\Users\aorla\Downloads\TheBestOfBaseballAwards\baseball_dataset.sql"



The first error means that "Postbird" is using a version of the PostgreSQL client shared library "libpq" that is too old. Upgrade your client software!
For the other errors, try to specify the path like this:
/c/Users/aorla/Downloads/...

If that doesn't do the trick, it may be that the user running the PostgreSQL server cannot access that path. In that case, try putting the file in a different directory.
